LabView: How do I use a Boolean Toggle switch to set my slider "Enable State" to "Disabled & grayed"
I have a Numeric Slide control and a Boolean Toggle switch
I can control the output of the Slide control with the Toggle (False = output always "0", True = output always slide value). But I'd also like to control the Appearance/Enabled State with the same Toggle:
False = Appearance/Enabled State = Disabled & grayed |
True = Appearance/Enabled State = Enabled
I've gone through every Property Node I can think of and I don't see a way of setting the  Enabled State. Specifically to Gray out the entire control. Does this Node not exist?

The property node is called "Disabled": https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Grayed-out-buttons-during-run-time/td-p/72083

I was stuck on Disabled thinking input was Boolean, when I discovered it was an Enum and "grayed" value was 2, All I needed was to invert the output of the Toggle, multiply by 2 and I get a "0" / "2" from the toggle and boom "Disabled & grayed"
